# what should be --worker-configs for kafka-connect-jdbc install on local docker setup

Tags: confluent-platform

I'm running confluent platform on local container. Trying to install jdbc connector plugin using confluent-hub cli.

1. It requires both --component-dir and --worker-configs

what should be the --worker-configs for the docker setup in local?

Answer (score 1):

Instead installing it from CLI, you can use confluent docker image and If I get your question rightly you can install the Docker container confluent provide.

In your Dockerfile you can add -

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.2.1
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest
COPY . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the command inside the CLI of the **connect** container.

First find out the container id. For that run the command `$ docker ps -a`

This will show something like that:

```
017c3b496934   confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:6.1.1                  "/bin/sh"                30 hours ago   Up 6 hours                                                      ksqldb-cli
3b75e28ee5b7   confluentinc/ksqldb-examples:6.1.1                "bash -c 'echo Waiti…"   30 hours ago   Up 6 hours                                                      ksql-datagen
cb244c1f9655   confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.1.1   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   30 hours ago   Up 6 hours     0.0.0.0:9021->9021/tcp                           control-center
ef7fc08ff259   confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.1.1               "/etc/confluent/dock…"   30 hours ago   Up 6 hours     0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp                           ksqldb-server
eb0e61b6cde9   cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.4.0-6.1.0   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   30 hours ago   Up 7 minutes   0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp, 9092/tcp                 connect
fa1cb887a7ff   confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.1.1                  "/etc/confluent/dock…"   30 hours ago   Up 6 hours     0.0.0.0:8082->8082/tcp                           rest-proxy
8d53c6c07660   confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.1.1             "/etc/confluent/dock…"   30 hours ago   Up 6 hours     0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp                           schema-registry
00780a262c09   confluentinc/cp-server:6.1.1                      "/etc/confluent/dock…"   30 hours ago   Up 6 hours     0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9101->9101/tcp   broker
06c2afc05440   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.1                   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   30 hours ago   Up 6 hours     2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp       zookeeper
```

Get the **id** from the **connect** container, in the case above *eb0e61b6cde9*

Then you can run any command inside the container with

```
$ docker exec -it <container_id> echo "Hello inside a container"
```

So in our case:

```
$ docker exec -it eb0e61b6cde9 confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest
```

After that it's straight forward. Just some questions pop up...